# Two divs/uls side by side inside a div that is Absolutely positioned

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a container that drops down like a notification container, I want to have two bars side by side inside the absolutely positioned div.I don't want to have to define a width because each div inside will need to adjust widths (because of the presence of a scrollbar or not)

The problem is odd, when .notification-wrapper has absolute or relative positioning the .left and .right divs won't align side by side, however when i remove absolute/relative from .notification wrapper they do...(i do need relative/absolute to be applied to notification.wrapper)

Here's what I have:

```
<span class="notification-wrapper">
<div class="notification-container">

<div class="left">LEFT</div>
<div class="right">RIGHT</div>

</div>
</span>




.notification-wrapper {
height: 32px;
width: 25px;
margin-right: -12px;
margin-left: -12px;
padding: 0px;
font-size: 0px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 15px;
right: 50%;
 }
.notification-wrapper .notification-container {
font-size: 12px;
background-color: #FFF;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 25px;
}
.notification-container .left {
vertical-align: text-top;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #63F;
width: 50px;
}
.notification-container .right {
vertical-align: text-top;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #FFC;
width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the CSS that you've tried?

Comment: Well, all I have right now is just right-bar and left-bar display:inline-block; vertical-align:text-top;

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LyLGX/)?

Comment: Why isn't that working for you?

Comment: Yeah, I just made a new page and did it the exact same way as I have on my regular page and it works perfect, hmm.. odd.

Comment: I have posted my new code above, with the problem. It's an odd problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you position an element it "shrink-wraps", meaning it shrinks to its smallest size. Since there's nothing *forcing* your two elements to reside side by side the smallest size it can get is if it stacks the elements instead.

I think, since you're using `inline-block` (rather than `float`), you could use `white-space: nowrap` on the container to force the two `inline-block` elements not to wrap. You will probably wanna set `white-space` back to `normal` for the contents of the elements though.

Also, a `span` element is an inline version of `div` and does not allow block level elements as children.

Comment: You can help other users find the right answer more easily by marking it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your code, Please try this code

```
.absolute-positioned{ overflow:hidden; float:left; width:auto;}
.absolute-positioned ul{ width:auto; list-style:none;display:inline-block; }
.absolute-positioned ul li{ display:inline-block; list-style:none; line-height:auto;}
.absolute-positioned ul.left-bar{ float:left; width:auto;}
.absolute-positioned ul.right-bar{ float:right; width:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. remove `width:25px` from `.notification-wrapper`
2. remove `position:absolute` and `top:25px` from `.notification-wrapper .notification-container`, instead use `padding-top:25px`
3. change `right:50%` in `.notification-wrapper` to `left:50%`